# Issue a 403 for certain nodes

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How do you issue a 403 for certain nodes? I tried using drupal_access_denied. While I got an Access Denied message, the watchdog is filled with:

**Cannot modify header information - headers already sent**

Is that normal? Am I not using drupal_access_denied right?

Comment: Where are you issueing that denied? In the theme, is too late. You can, however, issue that in a hook_nodeapi without problem.

Comment: hook_nodeapi in the load op is where I have it. Is it possible login toboggan is interfering?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the suggested [`hook_nodeapi()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_nodeapi) is still too late.

If you use the `$op = load`, you'll likely exhaust your memory because Drupal has already committed to all the normal things it does when it loads a node (including loading it multiple times).

If you use `$op = view`, you can "fake" it if you do the following:

```
function mymodule_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'view':
      drupal_access_denied();
      exit();
      break;
  }
}
```

But it's not a real 403: it won't be reported as such except in Watchdog, and all the normal stuff will still load and render as if the node was there.

For an easy hack, you could use [`hook_init()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_init):

```
function mymodule_init() {
  $nodes_403 = array(42, 69, 187);
  if (arg(0) == 'node' && in_array(arg(1), $nodes_403))
    drupal_access_denied();
    exit();
  }
}
```

But that's bypassing Drupal's built-in permissions system unnecessarily. Instead, you want to take advantage of Drupal's [node access rights](http://api.drupal.org/api/group/node_access/6) system to deny access to the node.

If you defined your own content type in the module, you could use [`hook_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_access):

```
function mymodule_access($op, $node, $account) {
  $nodes_403 = array(42, 69, 187);

  if (in_array($node->nid, $nodes_403)) {
    return FALSE;
  }
}
```

But if you don't define your own custom content types, `hook_access()` is never invoked. So instead, you need to override the node path's `access callback` with your own:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node']['access callback'] = 'mymodule_access';
}

function mymodule_access($op, $node, $account = NULL) {
  $nodes_403 = array(42, 69, 187);

  if ($op == 'view' && in_array($node->nid, $nodes_403)) {
    return FALSE;
  }

  return node_access($op, $node, $account);
}
```

Because of the [`hook_menu_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu_alter) implementation, make sure to rebuild your menu system after implementing the above.

Comment: I was able to get the 'headers' error to go away by doing drupal_access_denied(); break; at each check- but I will look at your method too. Wish this kind of explanation was in the API. http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_access_denied/6

Comment: @Kevin: the node access API is notoriously badly documented, which doesn't help when it's badly designed to begin with (why can I only use `hook_access()` when I define my own custom content type, and not on all nodes? Or for that matter, on *any* page). Drupal 7 cleaned up the API, so hopefully the documentation gets some love.

Comment: Yeah- I noticed this was breaking certain cron functions for user 0. I refactored to your method. Also, am I crazy, or does nodeapi view case not work like you'd expect?

Comment: @Kevin, the `view` operation in `hook_nodeapi()` is the non-node module complement to [`hook_view()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_view/6): it's mainly used to add additional fields to `$node->content`, and it's called extremely late in the node building process. By the time it gets called, you've already committed to displaying the node.

Comment: Gotcha. Used your method. What an odd quirk.

Comment: Important point about that last method (which is FANTASTIC - takes care of a major D6 quirk): don't call your access module `mymodule_access`. This is a reserved hook, and hook_access is what _doesn't_ work when you have to use that last method in the first place. You can call it anything you like, such as `mymodule_restrict`. Just make sure it matches what you specify as the access callback. Great help!